# Is there any way to make a COPY command on Dockerfile silent or less verbose?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, devops

We have a Dockerfile which copies the folder to another folder.

Something like
COPY . /mycode

But the problem is that there is tons of files in the generated code, and it creates 10K+ lines on the jenkins log where we are running the CICD pipeline.
copying /bla/blah/bla to copying /bla/blah/bla 10k times.

Is there a way to make this COPY less verbose or silent? jenkins admin has already warned us that our log file is nearing his max limit.

Comment: have you tried `docker build --quiet` or `docker build -q`? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Comment: You say your Dockerfile compiles the code and then copies the files to another folder. That doesn't fit with the `COPY` statement in your post which copies files from the host file system to the build image. If you're copying inside the image, I would expect the command would be `RUN cp . /mycode`. Can you make it a bit more clear what you're doing?

Comment: @mangusta docker build happens inside a tool based on jenkins where we dont have privileges to do this

Comment: @HansKilian You are right, we are copying from host system to the build image. I corrected original post.

Comment: @manumuraleedharan This is not exactly a solution, but are you trying to COPY the dependencies from the host directly to the image? It would be better to install them during the build, thus avoiding these logs. But yeah, if those 10k files are all your code and need to be copied you'll need to use the `-q` flag when issuing the build. Or, if as you say, it is __generated__ code, maybe it can be generated when building instead of copying it.

Comment: Of course, the right answer is to tell your Jenkins admin to buy some more disk. You've already spent enough time on this that buying more disk would have been cheaper :)

Comment: Please share an example Dockerfile. It's not clear how many `COPY` steps you have, if any, or if the output you are looking at is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: @HansKilian finally we went with RUN cp

Answer (score 1):

You can tar/zip the files on the host, so there's only one file to copy. Then untar/unzip after it's been copied and direct the output of untar/unzip to /dev/null.

Answer (score -2):

By definition the docker cp command doesn't have any "silent" switches, but perhaps redirecting the output may help, have you tried:

```
docker cp -a CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH|- &> /dev/null
```

I know it's not the most elegant, but if what you seek is to supress the console output, that may help.

Sources

[1] https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

[2] https://csatlas.com/bash-redirect-stdout-stderr/

Comment: The question is asking about the Dockerfile `COPY` directive, rather than the (imperative, shouldn't usually be necessary) `docker cp` command.